# How do I run a second JS script if first JS script produces no matches?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS that does an ajax call to check for certain data.  If that script returns no hits, I want to run a second script.

Heres the first script:

```
<div id='loading-gif'><img src='images/loading3.gif';></div>

          <div id='main-output'></div>

          <script>
              $('#loading-gif').hide();
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('#loading-gif').show();
                  $('#main-output').hide();
                  $.ajax({url: '$securebaseurl/scrape/getSegments.php?flightnumber=$flightnumber&datepicker=$datepicker'}).done(function (data) {
                      $('#loading-gif').hide();
                      $('#main-output').show();
                      output = JSON.parse(data);
                      $('#main-output').html(output);
                  });

              });

          </script>
```

If this script returns at least one hit, I want to stop and display the result.  If however, no results are returned, I want to run a second script:

```
<div id='loading-gif'><img src='images/loading3.gif';></div>

<div id='main-output'></div>

<script>
    $('#loading-gif').hide();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#loading-gif').show();
        $('#main-output').hide();

        $.ajax({url: '$securebaseurl/getSegments.php?flightnumber=$flightnumber&datepicker=$datepicker'}).done(function (data) {
            $('#loading-gif').hide();
            $('#main-output').show();
            output = JSON.parse(data);
            //document.write(output);
            $('#main-output').html(output);
        });

    });

</script>
```

So the final product should look sort of like:

```
<div id='loading-gif'><img src='images/loading3.gif';></div>

<div id='main-output'></div>

<script>
$('#loading-gif').hide();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loading-gif').show();
    $('#main-output').hide();
    $.ajax({url: '$securebaseurl/scrape/getSegments.php?flightnumber=$flightnumber&datepicker=$datepicker'}).done(function (data) {
        output = JSON.parse(data);

        if output==''  {

            $.ajax({url: '$securebaseurl/getSegments.php?flightnumber=$flightnumber&datepicker=$datepicker'}).done(function (data) {
                output = JSON.parse(data);


                ";
            }
        }

            $('#loading-gif').hide();
            $('#main-output').show();
            $('#main-output').html(output);
    });
});
</script>
```

And maybe rather than

```
if output==''
```

I might have something like:

```
if output=='Your query returned no results'
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks.

Alan

Comment: What is `$securebaseurl`  it looks like it's just in the HTML.  Which in that case it's not a PHP variable, it's just text.  `<?php echo $securebaseurl; ?>`

Comment: Sorry... $securebaseurl is contained in a configuration file and is the url to my site: https://example.com.  It's used by js/ajax to call the php scripts... and the code I pasted above is actually part of a php file on my site that users access when logged in, so $securebaseurl is prepended to the ajax url.  Sorry for the confusion.